# Laravel change home link

Tags: php, laravel

1. I have an address like `mywebsite.com` but i'd like to change its main page to `mywebsite.com/darthmaul`
2. I can't do that in my routes file because i have to revise all of my routes. Changing `"/"` route doesn't work for me:

   ```
   Route::get('/'){
      return Redirect::to('http://www.anotherpage.com');
   }
   //otherwise mywebsite.com/darthmaul will be my main page
   Route::get('darthmaul', function()
   {
       return View::make('pages.login');
   });
   ```

Any ideas, where should i check ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by you have to revise all of your routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'darthmaul'], function()
{
    // put your routes here
});
```